# LWC componet is not work in Offline mode

Tags: lightning-web-components, offline

I am creating LWC component for creating new Account Record
***JS***

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

import NAME_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Name";
import PHONE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Phone";
import WEBSITE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Website";
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry";
import TYPE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Type";

export default class CreateAccountRecord extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @api objectApiName;

  nameField = NAME_FIELD;
  phoneField = PHONE_FIELD;
  websiteField = WEBSITE_FIELD;
  industryField = INDUSTRY_FIELD;
  typeField = TYPE_FIELD;

  name = "";
  phone = "";
  website = "";
  industry = "";
  type = "";

  onSuccess(event) {
    console.log("Created account", event.detail);
    // Dismiss modal on success
    this.dismiss(event);
  }
}
```

***Html***

```
<template>
    <div class="component-background">
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account" onsuccess={onSuccess}>

            <div class="header-slot">
                <!-- cancel and submit buttons-->
                <lightning-layout horizontal-align="spread" class="slds-var-p-horizontal_xx-small">
                    <lightning-layout-item>
                        <lightning-button variant="base" data-id="cancel" label="Cancel" type="button" onclick={dismiss}
                            class="button"></lightning-button>
                    </lightning-layout-item>

                    <lightning-layout-item>
                        <lightning-button variant="base" data-id="submit" label="Create" type="submit"
                            class="button-primary"></lightning-button>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
            </div>



            <div class="header-offset slds-var-p-horizontal_small slds-var-p-bottom_medium">

                <!-- show any error messages or alerts -->
                <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

                <!-- input fields -->
                <lightning-input-field field-name={nameField} value={name}></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name={phoneField} value={phone}></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name={websiteField} value={website}></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name={industryField} value={industry}></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name={typeField} value={type}></lightning-input-field>

            </div>

        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </div>
</template>
```

and this componet is implement on Quick action All of these work fine in Online mode but when i use Salesforce moblie and try to create Account using this Quick action in Offline mode it will not work when user come back online.